# multiple JOIN in Cosmos db returns duplicate values when any two tables has same structure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

[Because of Select in query I was getting duplicates. I even used the Distinct keyword.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mePFJ.png)I am trying to fetch students with filters as shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMjf9.png). It's joining with diploma degree and normal degree seperately. I hope you can understand the query I am posting and solve.

> select DISTINCT c.userPrivateDetails.email, c.id,c.emailVerified,
>   c.createdOn, c.nboardVerified, c.userPrivateDetails.mobileNumber,
>   c.userBasicDetails.firstName,ed.degree degree,ed.branch
>   branch,ed.acadamicInstitution acadamicInstitution, ed.yearOfPassing
>   yearOfPassing from c join inter IN c.educationDetails  join ssc IN
>   c.educationDetails  join ed IN c.educationDetails where ed.degreeType
>   = 'highestOrPursuing' and udf.stringToNumber(ed.percentage) >=20 and udf.stringToNumber(inter.percentage) >=20 and
>   udf.stringToNumber(ssc.percentage) >=20

cosmos

> select DISTINCT c.userPrivateDetails.email, c.id,c.emailVerified,
>   c.createdOn, c.nboardVerified, c.userPrivateDetails.mobileNumber,
>   c.userBasicDetails.firstName,ed.degree degree,ed.branch
>   branch,ed.acadamicInstitution acadamicInstitution, ed.yearOfPassing
>   yearOfPassing from c join inter IN c.educationDetails  join ssc IN
>   c.educationDetails  join ed IN c.educationDetails where ed.degreeType
>   = 'highestOrPursuing' and udf.stringToNumber(ed.percentage) >=20 and udf.stringToNumber(inter.percentage) >=20 and
>   udf.stringToNumber(ssc.percentage) >=20

Wanted students with only ed degree and not inter or ssc

Can any one say how we can select from arrays of sub document in cosmos db

Comment: what's your sample data?

Comment: what's the exact results you get now? Any differences with your want?

Comment: Hi @JayGong, I added the image of the result I am getting and modified question also. kindly check it and say.

Comment: Sorry,still can't get your points.Just post sample simulate data and post your desire format of data ,which is direct and clear way here.